# Transform React project into Progressive Web App

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I created a web application (symfony backend and React frontend) and I'm interested in making a progressive web app. On the whole, it seems feasible. You need to create a manifest.json and a service worker.
However, I do not know where to create these two files so that it is taken into account when I make an npm run build (or even npm run dev server if it is feasible). When I drag these files into the root, the browser tells me that it does not find any of these files.

Answer (score 0):

You can bootstrap your application with the PWA template following the command below:

```
npx create-react-app YOUR_PROJECT_NAME --template cra-template-pwa
```

The argument `--template cra-template-pwa` is added to create an app with a service worker.

The directory of your newly created project contains the file `index.js`. Open it and find the following code:

```
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Here, you can see that the serviceWorker is not registered yet. You have to change the `unregister()` call to `register()`.

```
serviceWorker.register();
```

Configure the web app manifest for your progressive web app, that is located in the `manifest.json` file in **public** directory. Here, you need to alter the metadata that is responsible for the appearance of your application.

Comment: Thank you for your help but this is in the case where you create a new project. In my case, the project already exists.

Comment: For an existing project, you've to manually install the necessary packages using the npm command: `npm i workbox-background-sync workbox-broadcast-update workbox-cacheable-response workbox-core workbox-expiration workbox-google-analytics workbox-navigation-preload workbox-precaching workbox-range-requests workbox-routing workbox-strategies workbox-streams`

And also have to add `manifest.json` file inside the **public** folder, `service-worker.js` & `serviceWorkerRegistration.js` inside the **src** folder